# How can I use binary tree in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have to write a code in matlab using binary tree in order to count and put in order words.

anyone to give any hint please?

Thanks

Comment: Too broad. Please rephrase your question to something that can be concisely answered. What have you tried so far? I'd start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree.

Answer (score 3):

Binary trees are composed of nodes with 3 references: left, right, and value. You can build one of these nodes with a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html).

```
root = struct(left, 0, right, 0, value, 'honeybee')
```

As you add more words to your tree, you will set the left and right fields to new nodes, creating your recursive data structure.

```
root.left = struct(...)
```