# accessing binary search tree using struct in a for loop

Tags: matlab, struct, binary-search-tree

I want to create a binary tree in MATLAB. So I tried putting structs in structs to represent the nodes. The basic idea is as follows

```
node3 = struct('left',0,'value',5,'right',1);
node2 = struct('left',node3,'value',6,'right',1);
tree = struct('left',node2,'value',nan,'right',1);
```

say if I wan to create a path of my binary tree for the first element(row 1) of my matrix with value of 1100 (top_node->right->right->left->left->1). I wanted to do this in a for loop and add structs to tree as I got on as shown above.

it should look something like that

```
array = [1 1 0 0; 1 0 0 0; 1 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0] %such that 1100 returns 1 and 1000 returns 2 and so on 

for j=1:4
  for i=1:4   
     if (array(1,i) == 0)) 
       node = struct('left',0,'value',nan,'right',1); %temp node %the nan will be 1 when it reaches the last node
       tree.left = node;
     elseif (array(1,i) == 1))
       node = struct('left',0,'value',nan,'right',1);
       tree.right = node;
    end 
  end
end
```

This code is perfectly fine if I was trying to implement it for 1 iteration. Adding the second struct (up to 11) would be difficult because I would then have to use tree.right.right = node, and adding the 3rd struct (up to 110) would be tree.right.right.left = node. Unlike other languages such as c, there is no pointers in MATLAB. This makes it impossible for me to implement it inside a for loop as the path gets longer.

Is there a way to solve this or is there a better way to implement a binary tree in MATLAB?

Comment: There’s a duplicate, but it’s a bad question with a useless answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640251/how-can-i-use-binary-tree-in-matlab

Comment: I can see at least three ways to solve this, but I’d have to implement them and compare to know which is the better solution. One involves an array of structs, with child pointers being indexes into the array. Another involves a handle class to implement the nodes. Another involves recursive functions that return the whole branch they update. The first approach is likely the simplest and therefore the fastest.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Hi, I notice the duplicate before posting. But as you said, it doesn't really provide any information I don't already know. Thankyou for your recommendation. I will try it out and let you know.